# Where can I see the printer driver version on Windows?

Tags: windows, drivers, printer, version

My problem is that the print is OK on one Windows system and bad on anther system. That I will compare the printer driver versions.

Where can i see the driver version of an installed printer driver? I hope there are no large difference between XP, vista and 7.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is how to do that :

1. Login as "Administrator"
2. Run mmc
3. In the file menu select "Add/Remove Snap-in..."
4. Scroll down in the list and
   select the "Print Management"
   snap-in, then click "Add"
5. In the ensuing dialog, select "Add the Local Server", then click on Finish and then OK
6. Scroll down to your computer name, click on "Drivers" to display all printers, then
   right-click on the printer's name and select "Properties"
7. Scroll down to "Driver file", click on it, then click on the Properties button
8. The requested information is in the Details tab

Comment: God bless you! Windows is evil!

Answer (score 12):

On Windows 7:

1. Find the command prompt at %windir%\system32\cmd.exe
2. Right click and "Use as Administrator".
3. Type `printui /s /t2`.
4. This will pull up a page called print server properties.
5. Select an installed print driver.
6. Left click properties to bring up driver properties.
7. Left click the driver file.
8. Left click on properties.
9. Click on the details tab.

Inside you will find the file version and product version of the file.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way, if the printer is local, is to print the Test Page from the Windows Driver Properties as follows:

1. Open "Printers and Faxes"
2. Right click the appropriate printer icon and select "Printer Properties" if it's there, or else "Properties"
3. Click the "Test Page" button

The driver version should be listed on the test page that prints out.

There may be a way to redirect the output to a different printer or PDF Creator for remote diagnosis.

Answer (score 1):

Also, Go to Devices and Printers > Right Click on the appropriate Printer icon and select "Printer Properties"  -  Click on the (About) last TAB on the right. You will see the printer driver's version there.

Answer (score -2):

Driver version and other related information should be available under **Device Manager** (just search for 'devmgmt.msc').

Comment: Drivers for *most* devices do show up in Device Manager, but printers are handled differently and will never show up there.

Comment: That's odd, because I've just tried it on my printer and it's displayed there.

Comment: Weird, on my machine (Vista) with 1 USB and several network printers I don't see any printers there...  I do remember a printer back in the Win2000 days showing up in Device Manager now that I think about it.  The closest I have to a printer driver is a "USB Printing Support" driver in Device Manager

Comment: What connection do you have on your printer? I have seen them show up in device manager also but not all the time.

Comment: It's connected via USB. I suppose you're right in that it depends how the printer is connected/installed.

Comment: Mine is also connected via USB and I don't see it.

Comment: It actually is available now in Windows 10. Tried to edit with images etc, but idiot mods ...